# How to specify cache-control header with LitS3 Library? (Amazon File Upload)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, amazon-s3, cache-control

I'm using the [LitS3 library](http://code.google.com/p/lits3/) to help upload photos from my ASP.NET MVC application to Amazon S3.

I've read through all the documentation, googled around, and i can't figure out how to set the `cache-control` header for the photos when i upload them.

I know you can do it with the REST API, but as i'm using the LitS3 library, that's not an option (unless i scrap the library altogether).

Has anyone figured out how to do it?

I see the documentation there is a section for "want more flexibility" - which seemingly gives access to nearly 100% of the API, but can't see how i can apply that to my situation.

Here's how i'm currently uploading:

```
var s3 = new S3Service { AccessKeyID = _accessKey, SecretAccessKey = _secret };
s3.AddObject(inputStream, 
             _bucketName, 
             fileName, 
             contentType, 
             CannedAcl.PublicRead);
```

Where `inputStream` is a `Stream`, that i get from the `HttpPostedFileBase.InputStream` in my MVC action.

None of the `AddObject` overloads support setting any other header apart from content-type. So it looks like i need to dig deeper and use a lower-level method, but as i said - just can't find out how.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it! Thanks to [this thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=43651), which doesn't concern cache-control, but it shows how to use `AddObjectRequest` with a given `Stream`.

Here's the working code, if anyone else is interested:

```
// Create S3 service.
var s3 = new S3Service { AccessKeyID = _accessKey, SecretAccessKey = _secret };

// Create HTTP Request.
var request = new AddObjectRequest(s3, _bucketName, fileName)
{
    CacheControl = "max-age=864000",
    CannedAcl = CannedAcl.PublicRead,
    ContentType = contentType,
    ContentLength = inputStream.Length
};

// Upload photo.
using (var outStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    var buffer = new byte[inputStream.Length > 65536 ? 65536 : inputStream.Length];
    var position = 0;
    while (position < inputStream.Length)
    {
        var read = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        outStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        position += read;
    }
    outStream.Flush();
}

var response = request.GetResponse();
response.Close();
```